# Visual Studio C++ wont accept >> or << past the initial declarations

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I was testing some very simple things in Visual Studio 2015. For some reason, I cannot for the life of me, figure out why this simple program won't compile in Visual Studio 2015's C++ IDE. Here is the source code:

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <cstdlib>;
#include "stdafx.h";

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!";
    cout << "\nI am a C++ program!";
    cout << "\n\nWhat is your name? ";
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Nice to meet you, " << name;
}
```

It compiles `PERFECTLY` fine in http://www.cpp.sh, minus the `"stdafx.h"` library of course, since that's Visual Studio only. Here was what I got for

> error messages:
>
> 1>c:\users\orion\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(13): error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
>       1>  c:\users\orion\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(13): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::basic_ostream>, std::string)'

Something is strange, it must have to do with Visual Studio 2015. The app type is a standard Console application. I have looked and I can't really find an answer for this.

Comment: `#include <string>`?

Comment: You need to `#include <string>`.

Comment: @Monstarules: `<cstdlib>` is not a file to include the whole standard library. It just defines some macros like `EXIT_SUCCESS` and declares som functions like `exit`.

Comment: Don't add semicolons after the include directives.

Comment: for some reason the cstdlib must differ between applications

Comment: I doubt that this will still compile in Visual Studio, since with precompiled headers turned on (the default in a VS project) all the includes before the precompiled header, in your case `"stdafx.h"`, are ignored. You can **turn off precompiled headers in the project options**. Then you don't need that `"stdafx.h"`, and you get standard preprocessor behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does give said warning on Visual Studio 2015: http://rextester.com/YERLQA25808

To use [`string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) you need to `#include <string>`.

When you do it compiles and runs just fine: http://rextester.com/BKA25587

Comment: Yep thanks, I feel kinda dumb atm'

Comment: @Monstarules Trust me, we've all been there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `<string>`header to use `std::string` .

Comment: Yeaaaah that did it. I could have sworn it was included in my cstdlib

Comment: cstdlib differs between apps. Thanks

Comment: @Monstarules: See http://rextester.com/KKNKP15624

Answer (score 1):

The headers should be:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
```

Also you need `<string>` as noted by other answers. The `stdafx.h` causes all previous code to be discarded, so it must be the first line of your source file.